# Better syntax for returning error and data from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what syntax is better for returning data and error indicator from an async function.

**Option 1:**

```
dailyTasks.doSomething = async function () {    ​
    try {
        doSomethingHere();
        return [null, {
            status: 'done'
        }]
​
    } catch (e) {
        return [e, null];
    }
};
```

And then the call to this function will be:

```
const [error, data] = await dailyTasks.doSomething();
if (error){
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
dailyTasks.doSomething = async function () {    ​
    try {
        doSomethingHere();
        return {
            error: null,
            data: {
                status: 'done'
            }
        };
​
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            error: e,
            data: null
        };
    }
};
```

And then the call to this function will be:

```
const {error, data} = await dailyTasks.doSomething();
if (error){
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-create the Task or Either monads. It's worth looking into those as they represent a consistent way of handling data that might return an error. With Either, you get one of two results - frequently called "Left" and "Right". Left is if you get an error whole Right if there was none. You decide what those values are upfront and you get only one in the end, e.g., you try to fetch the username and get either "Bob123" or "user not found". With Task, you supply an error callback and a success one and execute the appropriate one depending on what result you get.

Comment: neither `const [error, data] = dailyTasks.doSomething();` nor `const {error, data} = dailyTasks.doSomething();` will work since an async function returns a Promise

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. Forgot the `await` before...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to catch errors on topmost call, e.g. I have server endpoint, there I call some business logic method:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await myBusinessFunction();
    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('internal  server error');
  }
})
```

Not in any subsequent call of myBusinessFunction I catch errors, only in endpoint.
You may need to catch errors if you call 3d party lib, to control its error codes, or if you introduce separate context, like with setTimeout, setInterval.

Comment: What if function a calls function b that calls function c to get some info. In this case it would be very hard to handle it in your way.

Comment: Absolutley not, I have full stack trace in topmost call catched error, so I can find that it was function c which failed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is async, it returns a Promise. The appropriate indicator for an error coming from an `async` function would probably be for the Promise that it returns to reject:

```
dailyTasks.doSomething = async function () {
  // do something asynchronous
  await doSomethingHere();
  return { status: done };
};
```

and

```
try {
  await dailyTasks.doSomething();
} catch(e) {
  // handle errors
}
```

Let the *consumer* handle the error as-is, if it occurs, without putting extra wrapping around it.

Comment: The function that calls this async function should call additional functions, so I want to know where the error comes from.

Comment: Also I read somewhere that it's not good practice to throw the error to the parent function.

Comment: Sure - put the `try`/`catch` *just* around the call to `doSomething`, and you'll know exactly where the error came from. Letting the parent caller handle errors *is* a fine way to design things - doing the opposite is often a code smell IMO. Not always, but often.

Comment: Sometimes function a calls function b that calls function c to get some info. In this case it would be very hard to handle it in your way.